# Edit Powerpoint Chart Data via VBA Script

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

i've a powerpoint presentation with a chart which contains data from an excel table.

I would like to edit this data via the powerpoint VBA editor..

how can i do this? i cant find a way to access the data of the excel table.

greets

Comment: Is your chart an Excel chart?

Answer (score 3):

This code allows you to access an Excel WorkSheet embedded into a PowerPoint presentation.

```
Sub a()

Dim oSl As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim oSh As PowerPoint.Shape

Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

Set oSh = oSl.Shapes(1)

With oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Sheets(1)
    .Range("A1").Value = .Range("A1").Value + 1
    .Range("A2").Value = .Range("A2").Value - 1
End With

Set oSl = Nothing
Set oSh = Nothing

End Sub
```

If the graph is linked to the data you modify, probably it'll update automagically. If not, force a re-calc.

HTH!

**Edit**

With the following change it works in Office 2007:

```
With oSh.OLEFormat.Object.WorkSheets(1)
    .Range("A1").Value = .Range("A1").Value + 1
    .Range("A2").Value = .Range("A2").Value - 1
End With
```

Comment: well that works only if i save the project as powerpoint 2003

Comment: otherwise i get an error that says "OLEFormat(unknown member): Invalid request. This property only applies to OLE objects.

Comment: Didn't test it in 2007 nor 2010. I almost always work in 2003 mode for compatibility with my clients' machines :(. Is that Ok?

Comment: it seems that i have no other option as using the compatibility mode :(

Comment: @darkdog I'll research a little, and come back if find another way.

Comment: @darkdog re-checked and working on mine ... perhaps some library reference issue

Comment: oh i think we missunderstood each other.. you are working in an excel worksheet.. but im working directly in powerpoint.. if i place a chart object in powerpoint it creates an excel worksheet in the background.. but i cant communicate with this excel worksheet from powerpoint

Comment: @darkdog That was a known bug in Excel 2007, so I always use Excel Charts. See for example http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00889.htm. Really I did not bother to know if MS ever fixed it. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @darkdog Also, please note that my first intervention on your post was the comment at your question **Is your chart an Excel chart?**. Regrettably you forgot to answer that one :D